# parsing int when doing json deserialization

Tags: c#

I'm writing a custom javascript converter and I'm receiving a string that should contain an int.
This is what I'm doing:

```
public class MyObjectToJson : JavaScriptConverter
{
public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{

  MyObject TheObject = new MyObject; 

  if (serializer.ConvertToType<int>(dictionary["TheInt"]) == true)
  {
    MyObject.TheInt = serializer.ConvertToType<int>(dictionary["TheInt"]);
  }
```

However, it's not working on the conditional statement. What do I need to change? I want to test that I'm getting an int.

Thanks.

Comment: `ConvertToType` is returning an `int`, not a `bool`.

Comment: if conversion was successfully, it returns an object of the request type. then, you're comparing an object with boolean value.

Comment: `I'm writing a custom javascript converter` Why?

Comment: @L.B: because I want to test to see if I'm getting the correct types of values

Comment: what's you trying to validate? really need do it by data types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to use this condition:

```
 int value;
 if (int.TryParse(serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheInt"]), out value)
 {
    MyObject.TheInt = value;
 }
```

This is a better solution than relying on an exception to be thrown, as catching exceptions is  computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2):

It's because ConvertToType returns an object of the requested type. To use it as a condition to an `if` clause it must return `bool`.

You can do it instead:

```
try {
    MyObject.TheInt = serializer.ConvertToType<int>(dictionary["TheInt"]);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not convert value into int: " + dictionary["TheInt"]);
}
```

**EDIT:** Earlier I proposed a check for null equality on the converted value, but realized that it's more likely for the method to throw an exception than returning null when the types mismatch.

Comment: @Doug: if can't do conversion, ConvertToType () give a exception. why do it again?

Comment: Just to give a more meaningful message. Maybe my message was not the case, but a message that describes what's happening in the application (rather than just telling you the value could not be converted) would help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not sure that the type cannot be an int, use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

```
MyObject TheObject = new MyObject; 

  if (!int.TryParse(dictionary["TheInt"], out MyObject.TheInt))
  {
    // conversion to int failed
  }
```